# Create folder in Instrumentation context

Tags: android, instrumentation, android-testing

I am writing instrumentation tests for my app and want to create a temporary folder to store some files. However, I dont want to do that in the targetContext but rather in the test context.

In other words:

```
// Works, but this creates the folder in the target app.
File dir = getInstrumentation().**getTargetContext()**.getDir("directory", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  

// Does not work, the exists() returns false.
File dir = getInstrumentation().**getContext()**.getDir("directory", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

I've tried a bunch of other stuff, it seems as if the `Instrumentation` `context` implementation ignores these calls?

Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed, it is probably a bug in Instrumentation.

Comment: I have encountered the same situation, and could not find a solution. This looks like a long-standing issue... And looking at the directory structure of the test package, there are no `files/`.